# How can i connect form_choices from flask-admin to flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I found in flask-admin documentaion attrubute form_choices, i have connected it with other function that provide choices from DB using flask-sqlalchemy.https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#customizing-built-in-views

```
  AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES = new_list
  form_choices = {
       type':AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES}
```

new_list is choices that i want to add to this field.
But when i updating new_list with other method choices isn't updating.
Any ideas how to connect to database?
I've just started to learn flask sorry if my question would be stupid for you.

I've tried to use db.relashionshop() from flask-sqlalchemy but that's not select field that i wanted.